# bootstrapTable() method leaves empty space under table data

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

currently I'm trying to add to my page a table, which loads data from API. I found a bootstrap table library. I have a problem with setting table height. I'd like to have a table which dynamically sets table height depending on a count of data loaded from API, but at the moment I have a couple of cells in table, and empty space under those cells. Sorry for my English, I wish I'd explained my problem fairly understandable. I think that a screen shot will show what's the point.

here is my code:

html

```
<table id="table"
    class="table table-responsive table-striped"                           
    style="background: whitesmoke;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
         <th data-field="firstname" data-sortable="true">Imię</th>
         <th data-field="lastname" data-sortable="true">Nazwisko</th>
         <th data-field="roomType" data-sortable="true">Typ pokoju</th>
         <th data-field="dateFrom" data-sortable="true">Początek</th>
         <th data-field="dateTo" data-sortable="true">Koniec</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

javascript

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
     data: reservations,
});
```

reservations is a list loaded from api

and here is a result

[how table looks on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkkRm.jpg)

how can I set table height depending on a number of data loaded from API?

Thank's for help : )

Comment: just asking have you tried `height: auto;` ?

Comment: @Ylama yeah, nothing changes

Comment: Or try this might work wrap the `table` inside a `div` called `table-responsive`  , so it would look like this `<div class="table-responsive"><table>...</table></div>` , its an Bootstrap class, since you are using bootstrap, also maybe remove it from `table` style tag

Comment: also without result

Comment: close this tag `class="table table-responsive table-striped"`    you need the `"` , was that maybe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think its an typo error on the `table` tag:

`class="table table-responsive table-striped"` this should be closed and yours is open if i look at the question snippet posted.

Like this:

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="background: whitesmoke;">
```

Comment: I've changed like you suggested, but with no effect : / there is still this empty space under cells with data

Comment: well then i need to delete

Comment: i amended my answer, helped ?

Comment: there could be other css that has an effect on your table `height`

Comment: I've closed the tag, but with no result. I also can't see any other css that could cause it

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a sulution. It was because my html document was missing  at the top. Now it works fine, thanks for help : )